# ¿Cómo hacer un programa (calculadora básica) al estilo prompt de Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buen día, tengo otra duda, estoy leyendo un libro de Python, me sale un ejercicio que no tengo ni idea de cómo resolverlo. Me pide que haga una calculadora básica, aritmética de suma, resta, multiplicación y división.
La verdad estoy comenzando en Python, pero no tengo la mínima idea de cómo hacer ese programa.
Hasta este momento, los temas que he leído del libro son:

```
Entrada y salida: input / print
condicionales if, elif, else
variables: {}
Operadores lógicos: and, or, not
```

Y ahora, para reforzar mi conocimiento, aparece el ejercicio, me pide que:
El usuario ingrese dos números (debe aceptar enteros o decimales);
El número se debe almacenar en dos variables: num1 y num2.
El usuario especificará qué operación aritmética se realizará.
Mostrar el resultado en pantalla.
Ejemplo:

```
6 + 4
10

30 * 3
90
```

Hasta lo que he hecho es esto:

```
num1 = float(input('Ingrese numero 1'))
num2 = float(input('Ingerse numero 2'))
```

Hasta ahí me quedé, no pude avanzar más, lo había hecho de otra forma:

```
num1 = float(input('Ingrese numero 1'))
num2 = float(input('Ingerse numero 2'))

suma = num1 + num2
print('La suma de {} y {} es {}'.format(num1, num2, suma))
```

Pero veo que mi forma de resolverlo no es el correcto.
¿Alguien puede decirme qué temas debo leer para resolverlo? O alguna sugerencia.

Comment: La solución depende mucho de cómo se supone que sea el input que debes aceptar. No es lo mismo, por ejemplo, pedirle al usuario primero un número, luego otro, y luego la operación a realizar entre ellos, que pedirle directamente una cadena y que  el usuario escriba "2+3" y tu programa deba generar el resultado (5). Y si es este segundo caso, la cosa también cambia si el usuaro debe poner espacios ("2 + 3") o no ("2+3"). Y siempre suponiendo que no pueda escribir expresiones más complejas, como "2 + 3 * 4". ¿Puedes aclarar cómo ha de ser la entrada?

Comment: Es el segundo caso.

Comment: El tema es que no parece posible implementar una solución sólo con los elementos que dices que habeis estudiado. Necesitas conocer también como iterar por cadenas de caracteres, y cómo crear cadenas agregando caracteres como mínimo. De ese modo puedes ir recorriendo los caracteres de la entrada del usuario verificando que todos sean números (lo que implica también conocer, bien el método `.isdigit()` o bien la pertenencia de una cadena a otra con el operador `in`) para ir agregándolos a una variable, extraer el símbolo de la operación a otra variable, y el segundo número a una tercera.

Comment: ... después convertir a entero las variables que contienen los números, y usar un condicional para hacer con ellos una operación u otra según la variable que contenga el símbolo. O eso, o conocer expresiones regulares para extraer más fácilmente los números y el símbolo.

Comment: También puede leer la expresión completa y llamar a `eval` ...